# Difference between Hilbert spaces $H^1$ and $H^1_0$

Tags: functional-analysis

I know the definition of the Hilbert space $H^1(\Omega)$ (and in general $H^m$), but I cannot find the definition of $H^1_0(\Omega).$ Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Close after starting with functions which are compactly-supported in the open region.

Answer (score 2):

The subscript $0$ usually refers to homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. For example, $H^1_0([a,b]) = \{ f \in H^1([a,b]) : f(a) = f(b) = 0 \}$. In one dimension this makes sense as written, since 1D $H^1$ functions are continuous. In general this requires a little bit of work with traces to be properly defined.

Answer (score 1):

$H^1_0(\Omega)$ is the closure in $H^1(\Omega)$ of the $C^\infty$ functions with compact support in $\Omega$.